# Is Nvidia GPU mining software available for OSX?

Tags: gpu-mining, macos

Title says it all... I am looking for an Nvidia GPU miner for OSX. I've got a 2012 MBP i7 with Nvidia 650m, would prefer to mine without using Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You might use Tsiv's miner here: https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/releases but you will have to build it from source. I don't see any OSX binaries available.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* mine using https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/releases
But on a MBP with NVIDIA 650M, I wouldn't recommend it to you, since you will break your hardware sooner than you could imagine. A standard notebook is not designed to run it's GPU or CPU on 100% all the time. Really.

Nevertheless the hash rate of the integrated graphics is really not worth trying.

Comment: An NVIDIA 650M probably isn't worth mining from, but it definitely isn't integrated graphics.

Comment: You are right, corrected it.